# A question about inverse square matrix on division ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, division-ring

Does every square matrix on a division ring which has a left inverse have also a right inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the same reason as over a field: if you interpret matrices as endomorphisms of vector spaces, then left/right invertibility corresponds to surjectivity or injectivity, and over division rings an injective/surjective linear map between finite dimensional spaces of the same dimension is an isomorphism (because there is a well-behaved theory of dimension).

Comment: I totally understand it.